# Laravel File Uploading | Fetching Files from MySQL Database to view in laravel

Tags: php, css, mysql, laravel

I do not now how to show my files from laravel. the database contains path for the files and now I need to fetch my files and display them in laravel.

**files.blade.php**

```
@extends('dashboard.layouts.dashboard-layout')
@push('css')



@endpush



@section('content')

<div class="d-flex vw-100 vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
<img src="storage/{{$savedfile->filename}}" alt="">
</div>

 <div class="d-flex vw-100 vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('dashboard.files')}}">
            @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploadedfile" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-success">Upload the file</button></div>
              </form>
        </div>

@endsection

@push('script')

@endpush
```

The `<img src="storage/{{$savedfile->filename}}" alt="" />` is the file needs to be shown

**Fileupload Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Fileupload;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileuploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function files(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('uploadedfile');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = time(). '.' .$filename;
    
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/docs', $filename);
    
        Fileupload::create(['filename' => $path]);

        return view('dashboard.files')->with('savedfile', $savedfile);

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Fileupload  $fileupload
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Fileupload $fileupload)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is the controller for posting and returning the files.
The `return view('dashboard.files')->with('savedfile', $savedfile)` is the code to return and view my files.

However...

This is the error I'm getting

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RyUy.png)

I do not know why but its stressing already

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear.`$savedFile` is undefined .so you have change it like below

```
public function files(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('uploadedfile');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = time(). '.' .$filename;
    
       $file->storeAs('public/docs', $filename);
    
        Fileupload::create(['filename' => $path]);

         $path ="docs/".$filename;
      
        return view('dashboard.files')->with('savedfile', $path);

    }
```

or

```
public function files(Request $request)
        {
            $file = $request->file('uploadedfile');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = time(). '.' .$filename;
        
           $file->storeAs('public/docs', $filename);
        
            Fileupload::create(['filename' => $path]);
    
          
         $path = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url("docs/".$filename)
            return view('dashboard.files')->with('savedfile', $path);
    
        }
```

so in your view

```
<img src="{{asset($savedfile)}}" />
```

**Updated**
Also better way is to create separate file system for doc like below

In `config/filesystem.php`

```
 'docs' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/docs'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/docs',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and in your controller

```
$path=Storage::disk('docs')->url($filename);
```

so in your blade file

```
<img src="{{$savedfile}}" />
```

Comment: $path is still undefined

Comment: try  $path="docs".$filename;.before returning view

Comment: updated two options .let check updated answer